# Python: How to merge multiple csv files on the same input line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

How to open and merge multiple csv files on the same input line?

```
import csv
file=input("Enter the csv files:")
f= open(file, 'r')
r=csv.reader(f)
for row in r:
    print(row)
```

So when entered for 'file' it would be like "Enter the csv files:may.csv,june.csv.july.csv"

So how do you open and merge each of these files? They all have the same header.
I know this format is probably really bad, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
    import csv
    files = input("Enter the csv files:")
    for file in (f.strip() for f in files.split(',')):
        with open(file) as f:
            r = csv.reader(f)
            next(r)    # Skips the header
            for row in r:
                print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to do it.
import pandas as pd

```
a = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rshuell001\\Desktop\\excel_files\\Book1.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rshuell001\\Desktop\\excel_files\\Book2.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on='numbers')
merged.to_csv("C:\\Users\\rshuell001\\Desktop\\excel_files\\Book3.csv", index=False)
```

OR

import pandas as pd

```
a = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rshuell001\\Desktop\\excel_files\\Book1.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rshuell001\\Desktop\\excel_files\\Book2.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on='numbers')
merged.to_csv("C:\\Users\\rshuell001\\Desktop\\excel_files\\Book3.csv", index=False)
```